# CSS position:absolute + dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `<div>` tags one after the other, all in `position:absolute` and I align them using `top` and `left`.

The 3rd div tag contains dynamic content and the height of the div changes according to the amount of text in it. However, as I set the `top` and `left` of all divs, the 4th div is affected by the height of the 3rd dynamic div.

How can I solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/25Xrh/

Comment: do they ought to be absolutely positioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try wrapping the 4 divs in a parent div and absolutely positioning that. Then you can allow the position of one of the children divs to affect another.

http://jsfiddle.net/25Xrh/5/

The solution you had meant that no matter what you tried to affect the `top:60px` and `left:180px` stopped it from moving anywhere other than this, so the dynamic content div wasn't able to reposition it.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this if instead of position:absolute the position was 'fixed'?

Comment: fixed position means that it stays there constantly. If you scroll, it stays where it is. For example, you see on some websites that as you scroll down the page the navigation stays visible always, that's fixed positioning. It's usually best practice to wrap divs anyhow, it allows you to reposition multiple divs at once very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test:
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/25Xrh/7/

Code:

```
.first {
    position:relative;
    left:180px;
}

.second {
    position:relative;
    left:180px;
}

.third {
    position: relative;
    left:180px;
}

.fourth {
    position:relative;
    left:180px;
}
```