# Setting height of fixed element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a page that breaks the default page functionality. It's gonna work like this:

Once you first start scrolling the page, a splash-sort-of-screen fades down whilst the background and splash are fixed, once you have scolled something like 2400px, the scroll starts to behave as normal. This is the solution i'm working on:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   </p>Rest of the content</p>
</div>
<div class="splash" >
   <p>Splash-content that has 100% height and width</p>
</div>
```

Once you load the page, both div:s are set to position fixed. I then listen for scroll-events and set the opacity of the splash based on how far down the page has scrolled. Once the page has scrolled so far so that the splash has opacity: 0, I set the wrapper to display: static and margin-top: 2400, to make the transition to normal scrolling behaviour. (this is done using `addClass(fixed)` below.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrolllength = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    switch(true) {


        //y2004 starts to show
        case (scrolllength > y2004):
            console.log('above 2004 bottom')
            $('.wrapper').removeClass('fixed');
            break;


        //y2003 is fully visible
        case (scrolllength > y2003bottom):
            console.log('below 2003 bottom')
            $('.wrapper').addClass('fixed')

            $('.splash').css('display','none');
            $('.text').fadeIn('fast');

            break;

        //scrolling up, splash starts to show again
        case (scrolllength < y2003bottom && scrolllength > 0):
            console.log('above 2003 bottom '+scrolllength)
            var splashopacity = ((y2003bottom -scrolllength)/y2003bottom );
            $(".splash").css('opacity',(splashopacity));
            //show the splash again
            $('.splash').css('display', 'block');
            $('.text').fadeOut('fast');
            break;


        //default
        default:
            console.log(scrolllength);
            return;
    }
});
```

fixed css:
    .fixed{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

This approach works well. The only problem is that when I set the wrapper to "fixed" it loses it's height. This in turn makes it impossible to scroll. I would like the document to expand the window-size based on the content of .wrapper. Or any other solution that achieves a similiar goal. Css is preferred but javascript is fine aswell!

Comment: probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102395/css-positionabsolute-dynamic-height (found with google as 1st hit with: css fixed element with dynamic size)

Comment: I don't use position: absolute, but static. I'm gonna look in to that queystion, but I don't think it's gonna help for me, thanks thoug!

Comment: I created a new question which hopefully is a bit clearer without all the background-info that is not really relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650616/set-body-to-height-of-contianing-fixed-element

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, absoulte and fixed have the same behavior for sizes

Comment: It would be helpful if you also provide the css for class "fixed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set it to `position: absolute;`, and it has no non-statically positioned parents, that should fix it. As you've noted, fixed elements don't contribute height to the document, whereas absolute ones do.

Setting the body height to the wrapper height will give you scroll behavior with fixed positioning, if that's what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/ULLBw/3/

```
<div class='wrapper'>click me</div>
```

js

```
$('.wrapper').on( 'click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fixed');
});

$('body').height( $('.wrapper').height() );
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0

    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.wrapper.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Well... I'm trying to achive fixed-position-behaviour. With this approach, when I scroll the page the element isn't fixed...

Comment: I guess I don't understand the requirements. If the wrapper has fixed behavior, but content longer than the screen, you'll never see the rest of the content, right ? Or do you want everything to stay in place until you reach some distance ?

Comment: Yes, that's exacty! When I start scrolling some other things are happening on the screen, but after a while I want it to fallback to default behaviour :)

Comment: The approach i'm looking at right now is getting the height of the contaning elements using javascript and then set the body to that

Comment: I can't see it? Where?