# Set body to height of containing fixed element?

Tags: css

I have a body with a wrapper

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">//loads of content</div>
</body>
```

The wrapper is set to `position: fixed;` Because of special scroll-behaviour and javascript. I would like the body to have the same height as the wrapper.

(If anyone is intersted in why I try to achive this I try to explain my problem here:
[Setting height of fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650325/setting-height-of-fixed-element?noredirect=1)
But I felt the question got overly complicated for anyone who wants to solve this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can set `.wrapper`'s height that is of body through CSS like this:

```
height: inherit;
```

Here `inherit` will take out its parent's height and then set it as its.

Second thing, you need javascript for that because if you will use CSS then I am afraid you will not be able to control the size of the body when resizing.

With CSS:

```
height: whatever_body_height
```

With JS:

```
function getDocHeight() { /*For cross-browser*/
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
window.onresize = function () {
    document.getElementByClassName('.wrapper').style.height = getDocHeight();
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: concerning inherit, with that height, it sets the height to the height of the window, rather than the containing elements

Comment: that's allright though, I don't need to change the height of the wrapper, but rather the body

Comment: Also, the javascript seems to get the height of the window rather than the height of all the containing elements

Comment: The approach i'm looking at right now is getting the height of the contaning elements using javascript and then set the body to that